# How to Validate pair in the ICE protocol?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, ice-protocol

Related WebRTC, ICE protocol gives the which pair of addresses will work for direct media transfer between the pairs.

Let A and B are two endpoints

1. To choose which address will work for direct communication between A and B, Person A first gather candidates, encode candidate attribute, encode the SDP offer message, and send it to another endpoint.
2. When B get offer message from A,then person B gather candidates, encode the SDP answer message with its own list of candidates and send it to person A.
3. At this end of this process, each agent has a complete list of local candidates and Remote candidates. Its pairs them up, resulting in CANDIDATE PAIRS. To see, which pair work, each agent performs the connectivity checks using STUN req/resp.

How many connectivity checks are performed, to nominate valid candidate pair?

What are the remaining ICE connectivity checks are performed regarding webRTC call?

To develop ICE module for webRTC call, I have to follow each step in RFC5245 or any thing else?

Answer (score 0):

> How many connectivity checks are performed, to nominate valid
> candidate pair?

The number of candidate pairs are the number of connectivity checks done by each side.

> What are the remaining ICE connectivity checks are performed regarding
> webRTC call?

There are no extra ICE connectivity checks for webRTC.

> To develop ICE module for webRTC call, I have to follow each step in
> RFC5245 or any thing else?

You have to implement or use existing implementation of [DTLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6347) protocol, [RFC5763](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5763) and [RFC5764](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5764). DTLS implementation can be found on OpenSSL library.

All these seems a lot of work but if you use openssl then its easy enough.

Comment: To develop ICE module for webRTC call, the agents perform the connectivity checks, then select the valid candidate pair. is any short way to choose valid candidate pair for webRTC?

Comment: No there is not if you use ICE. You can choose to  use other protocols or modify ICE by removing some candidate pairs depending on the type of NAT peers are behind. But that won't work with browsers.

Comment: In webRTC call, is any another way to choose pair of addresses?